# How to append serial data on textbrowser pyqt5 receiving from serial port python pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtserialport

My goal is to create a GUI using PyQt5 with functionality to receive data from serial port.

- This data should be printed into text browser inside the GUI.
- Data should be printed there continuously.
- Reading should be toggled by pushing button.

This is the GUI part of the code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 60, 101, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, -10, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 141, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 201, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 240, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 330, 251, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 651, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 381, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 371, 731, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.textBrowser_2.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.Clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 330, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Clear.setFont(font)
        self.Clear.setObjectName("Clear")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 330, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 60, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Connect)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)  
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

This is the reading function:

```
def Connect(self,MainWindow):
    port=self.comboBox.currentText()
    baudrate=self.comboBox_2.currentText()

    serialPort = serial.Serial(port = port, baudrate=baudrate,
                bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

    serialString = " "                     


    while(1):
        if(serialPort.in_waiting > 0):
            serialString = serialPort.readline()
            print(serialString.decode('ascii'))
            serialPort.write(b"Thank you for sending data \r\n")
```

Comment: I have skipped the retranslateui part

Comment: Please include the code for the serial port part.

Comment: @JakubSzlaur sir I did related changes

Comment: Hi, you can't have two functions with the same name (in your case `Connect`). Try changing that.

Comment: Hi @JakubSzlaur I forget to delete that repeat code.I changed my code. Actually I can see my desired output on the console. I just want to append that to the text browser and I think it is problem of "QtSerialPort". I don't know much about qtserialport.

Comment: By text browser you mean some `QtWidget`?

Comment: yes sir@JakubSzlaur

Comment: Did my answer helped you or no?

Comment: Not yet.. I'll inform you once get resolved

Answer (score 0):

So to append any text to the textBrowser simply use this line of code:

```
self.textBrowser.append(serialString.decode('ascii')) #Append text to the GUI
```

---

- But you are using `while` loop inside a GUI. **This wil cause the
  whole GUI to freeze and your app won't responded to any of your
  input.**
- You have to use threading for you to don't freeze the GUI.

Assert this to your code:

```
import Threading
...

   #This should go instaed of the line 140: self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Connect)
   self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: Threading.Thread(target = self.Connect).start())

...
```